# Floating Action Button on RecycleView Overlap

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to create an app with Floating Action Button at top of my RecycleView on Fragment, can someone guide me how can i put my floating action button that will overlap my RecycleView without putting it on MainActivity?

i want to remove this part [image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.filing.timelog.TimelogFilingFragment">
   <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
         android:id="@+id/pullFilingTimelog"
         android:layout_weight="4"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:id="@+id/rvFilingTimelog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
   <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        style="@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/borderColor"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:tint="#FFFFFF"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please share some image or sketch of the screen you want?

Comment: No Need to put in your activity,Just put it in your fragment. If you need code I would write some code to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.filing.timelog.TimelogFilingFragment">
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/pullFilingTimelog"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:id="@+id/rvFilingTimelog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        style="@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/borderColor"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:tint="#FFFFFF"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am adding an example code (as same as your code with the expected result) using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/pullFilingTimelog"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/floating_action_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvFilingTimelog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="never">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        style="@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/borderColor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:tint="#FFFFFF" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@layout/app_toolbar"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_asset_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_camera"
        app:rippleColor="@color/white" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/messages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="451dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```